# how to use multi choice spinner in mono for android?

Tags: xamarin.android, spinner

I want to use multi choice spinner in mono for android.
I want to bind the countries to the spinner
Now in the normal spinner there is label with radio button.
But I want the label with the Checkbox.

can any one please help me.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        CareCardActivity.this);
alt_bld.setTitle("Select Recepients");
alt_bld.setMultiChoiceItems(tempname, new boolean[tempname.length] , new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
            boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
alt_bld.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ListView list = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();

        Log.v("LIST COUNT:: ", ""+list.getCount());
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
            boolean checked = list.isItemChecked(i);

            if (checked) {
                sb.append(contactNumber[i]).append(";");
            }
        }
        sb = sb.replace(
                sb.length() - 1,
                sb.length(), "");
        txtPhoneNo.setText(sb.toString());
    }
});

alt_bld.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
alert.show();
```

I have tried this code in the eclipse it is working fine in it, but I want to do it for Mono develop in C#.

Comment: There is a difference between a radio button and a checkbox. So what you are asking for is a multi-select spinner? Also stackoverflow is for questions in specific pieces of code which you cannot get to work and not for giving you ready solutions, so please add what YOU have tried in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call this function on click of button

```
ShowDialog(DIALOG_MULTIPLE_CHOICE);
```

Add Following Code

```
protected override Dialog OnCreateDialog(int id)
    {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, OnDateSet, date.Year, date.Month - 1, date.Day);



        case DIALOG_MULTIPLE_CHOICE: {
            var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
            //          builder.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.ic_popup_reminder);
            builder.SetTitle ("Select Country");
            builder.SetMultiChoiceItems (countryName, new bool[countryName.Length], MultiListClicked);

            builder.SetPositiveButton ("ok", OkClicked);
            builder.SetNegativeButton ("Cancel", CancelClicked);

            return builder.Create ();
        }
        }
        return null;
    }
    private void MultiListClicked (object sender, DialogMultiChoiceClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("countryMultiListClicked");
        if (e.IsChecked) {
            mSelectedItems.Add (countryName [(int)e.Which]);
            mSelectedItemsID.Add (countryID [(int)e.Which]);
        }
        else if (mSelectedItems.Contains(countryName [(int)e.Which]))
        {
            mSelectedItems.Remove(countryName [(int)e.Which]);
            mSelectedItemsID.Remove(countryID [(int)e.Which]);
        }
    }
    private void OkClicked (object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("countryOkClicked");

        String listString = "";
        for (int i =0; i<mSelectedItems.Count; i++) {
            listString += mSelectedItems [i] + ",";
        }
        if (listString.Length > 0) {
            listString = listString.Remove (listString.Length - 1);
        }
        et_country.Text = listString;

        listStringId = "";
        for (int i =0; i<mSelectedItemsID.Count; i++) {
            listStringId += mSelectedItemsID [i] + ",";
        }
        if (listStringId.Length > 0) {
            listStringId = listStringId.Remove (listStringId.Length - 1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine (listStringId);
    }
    private void CancelClicked (object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("countryCancelClicked");
    }
```

This works fine ........!